# Problems with Android CSS spritesheet webkit transforms and animations

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, webkit

I'm relatively new to HTML5 and to Android, so any advice is useful. I'm trying to write a simple game in HTML5, mainly targetting mobile devices. I'm using spritesheets for the graphics, and "3d" webkit translation transforms to force hardware acceleration on iOS devices. It's working pretty well so far, runs pretty well on iOS devices, and also in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. My problem is with the browser on Android devices (testing with Android 2.3.3 on an HTC Desire) - I'd expect it to behave like Chrome, but apparently I'm wrong. It seems that Android supports webkit stuff, but has problems with 3d translate and CSS animations (even if they don't use 3D translates).

The following is my attempt to boil the problem down to its core. testimage.png can be anything, but for me it's a 3*3 grid showing numbers arranged like this:

```
012
345
678
```

The output on iOS, Chrome and Safari shows the parts of the texture corresponding to 0, 2 and 3 in a vertical line, with the 2 animating up and right. On Android, the animating "2" (and/or the 3d-transformed "1" if you uncomment the code) displays the whole image rather than the subset defined by the size of _spriteDiv, and whilst the animation is happening the "3" suffers the same problem.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Android Sprite Test</title>  
        <style>
        @-webkit-keyframes testAnim { from { -webkit-transform:translate(32px, 96px) } to { -webkit-transform:translate(256px, 0px) } }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor = "#606060">
        <script src="./scripts/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var MakeSprite = function() {
    var me = {},

    _width = 32,
    _height = 32,
    _spriteFrame = 1,

    _spriteDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    _spriteImg = document.createElement('img');

    _spriteDiv.id = 'spriteDiv';
    _spriteDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    _spriteDiv.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    _spriteDiv.style.width = _width + 'px';
    _spriteDiv.style.height = _height + 'px';

    _spriteImg.id = 'spriteImg';
    _spriteImg.src = './testimage.png';
    _spriteImg.width = Math.floor(_width * 3);
    _spriteImg.height = Math.floor(_height * 3);
    _spriteImg.style.position = 'absolute';

    _spriteDiv.appendChild(_spriteImg);
    document.body.appendChild(_spriteDiv);

    me.setFrame = function(n) {

        _spriteFrame = n;

        _spriteImg.style.left = (-_width * (_spriteFrame % 3)) + 'px';
        _spriteImg.style.top = (-_height * Math.floor(_spriteFrame / 3)) + 'px';
    };

    // Works on iOS, Safari and Chrome - but not Android?
    me.translate3d = function(x, y) {
        _spriteDiv.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px,0px)';
    }

    // Works on Android, but presumably lacks the hardware acceleration of the 3D version
    me.translate2d = function(x, y) {
        _spriteDiv.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
    }

    me.testAnim = function() {
        _spriteDiv.style.webkitAnimation = 'testAnim 5s';
    }

    return me;
};

/////////////////////////////////

// TEST SPRITES
// 2D translate works fine, but is suboptimal
var testSprite = new MakeSprite();
testSprite.translate2d(64, 32);
testSprite.setFrame(0);

// 3D translate doesn't work (it shows the whole image rather than clipping it),
// and it also breaks anything that comes after it
/*
var testSprite2 = new MakeSprite();
testSprite2.translate3d(64, 64);
testSprite2.setFrame(1);
*/

// CSS Animation breaks the sprite in the same way that 3D translation does
// (even though the animation works on a 2D translate), and similarly breaks
// sprites that come after it
var testSprite3 = new MakeSprite();
testSprite3.translate2d(64, 96);
testSprite3.setFrame(2);
testSprite3.testAnim();

// This will look wrong if any preceding sprites use translate3d or testAnim.
var testSprite4 = new MakeSprite();
testSprite4.translate2d(64, 128);
testSprite4.setFrame(3);
```

Does anyone know how I can get round these problems, so I can use CSS animations (and, ideally, hardware-accelerated webkit transform) on current version of the Android browser? I've heard noises about the support for this kind of thing being less buggy in future versions of Android, but to be honest I could really do with something that works on the current versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this, and I came across the following: http://caniuse.com/transforms3d.  Apparently, anything version that's < 3 doesn't support 3D transforms, which is a little disappointing.

Comment: I've bitten the bullet and accepted the lack of support for 3D transforms. I got round the problem I had here by giving up on the idea of using sprite sheets, and accepting that scaling sprites on Android is also impossible, so I'm just moving imgs around using 2D transforms. Even with those restrictions, the CSS animations are completely broken on Android. The images flicker like crazy things at the end of the animations, and they sometimes fail to fire off the callbacks when the animation finishes. It seems that Webkit is as good as useless on all but the newest version of Android.